# Programmatically deny a direct PayPal payment

Tags: paypal

Is there a way to programmatically deny (or "unclaim") a direct PayPal payment?

Let's say someone sends ten payments of $1 each to a corporate account. This is already an accounting headache, but if you think you can refund them as they never happened, there's a non-refundable part of a commission. Ten payments will cost you $3 USD or about as much in other currencies no matter what. This is infinitesimal amount business-wise, but related accounting expenses can be ten or even hundred times as much depending on which country a business in.

So best case would be to reject such payments *before* they even happen.

I read about IPN notifications, but nowhere there's mentioned a possibility to respond to a specific payment event with some sort of refusal. Yet I saw sometimes my own payments made by using standard "Pay Now" buttons to some merchants were tagged as `Unclaimed` until a manual intervention from the merchant. Therefore there must a be a way to do this.

Comment: It looks like 'unclaimed' means ['unable to accept'](https://www.paypal.com/uk/selfhelp/article/why-am-i-being-asked-to-accept-or-refuse-a-payment-i-received-faq1885) e.g. because the payment is in a currency you aren't set up to receive. So that probably isn't a mechanism you can use.

Comment: @Rup well, that's unfortunate. Anyway, let's see if another solution comes up.